# How to get rid of xmlns="" by setting project namespace

Tags: c#, xml

When I run the following code to add an element with an attribute it always adds xlmns="" at the end.  I've read that I need to set the namespace for it's parent or something like that.  The thing that's weird is that in the file the parent item *does* have the namespace set already so I don't quite know why that wouldn't be already be accounted for when the document gets loaded.  But either way, I just want to know how to tell it the namespace is there so it will stop adding the xlmns="" to the end of everything.

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load(projectFile);

// ...
// ...

var n = xDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Compile", null);
var a = xDoc.CreateAttribute("Include");
a.Value = filePath;
n.Attributes.Append(a);  
itemGroupNode.AppendChild(n);
xDoc.Save(@"c:\projects\BusinessObjects\BusinessObjects.csproj");
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)?

Comment: @dtb I don't work with xml much (at least, not other than serialization where I don't actually have to mess with xml myself).  This is a pretty small tool I need to do quick so I'm just doing it the fastest way I can figure out how to do it.  If I find myself needing to do more xml though then I'm sure I will use that.

Comment: The old XmlDocument/XmlElement classes are a pain to work with compared to the XDocument/XElement classes of LINQ to XML. Try it! :-)

Comment: If I hadn't just finished my tool I definitely would, and I definitely will the next time I need to work with xml :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're adding an element with namespace `""` to an element with namespace `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"`. This means that the new element needs an `xmlns`  attribute.

If you add an element with namespace `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"`, no `xmlns` attribute is needed (because it's inherited from the parent element):

```
var n = xDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Compile",
            "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003");
```

Comment: Cool, that worked.  Is there no way to tell it to look to the parent node for that info though?

Comment: Assuming *itemGroupNode* is an [XmlElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.aspx), you can use *itemGroupNode.[NamespaceURI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.namespaceuri.aspx)* to get the namespace instead of hard-coding it.